# Nuget looking in "\.nuget\packages" for local project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm working on an app with several projects in the solution. Project-1 builds fine and Project-2 references it within the same solution. When I open the references to Project-2, I see the Project-1 reference. I can go to the path specified and I see the Project-1 dll there.

When I try to build Project-2, I get the error

```
The package Project-1 could not be found in C:\Users\[it me]\.nuget\packages. 
Run a NuGet package restore to download the package.
```

Both projects are set to the same architecture (x64), not "Any CPU". Why is Project-2 looking for Project-1 in the nuget packages folder instead of the path specified?

Comment: Is it mentioned in your `packages.config`? Right-click on your project and select `Unload Project`, then right-click it again and select `Edit *.csproj file`. What is the reference path to your project?

Comment: I don't see that there is a package.config file anywhere in the solution. The reference in Project-2 is "..\Project-1\Project-1.csproj", so I know it should be pointing to the same solution.

Is there a VS-wide setting that maybe I'm missing? Something that isn't a part of the solution?

Comment: @MatthiasS, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Would you please convert your comment to answer and mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as it turned out, was a versioning problem. Project-1 had a lower target version than Project-2 (which was targeted for the Windows 10 Anniversary Build 14393). I installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, which includes the 14393 APIs, and that resolved the problem.